# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_valid_locations_'

Tags: python, class

I start with the assumption that I have already looked at many other posts related to the "builtin_function_or_method" error, but I have not found a solution to my problem. I really hope that someone has a moment to read because I write this post out of exhaustion.

To summarize: the following piece of code invokes the "get_valid_locations_" function

```
valid_locations = eval.get_valid_locations_(board)
```

The method I call is a function of the Evaluate class that I have previously imported in this way (I attach both how I imported the file and how I instantiated the object)

```
from Utilities import evaluate    
eval = evaluate.Evaluate()
```

While the function is as follows

```
def get_valid_locations_(self, board):
    valid_locations = []
    for col in range(NUMS_COL):
        if eval.is_valid_location(board, col):
            valid_locations.append(col)
    return valid_locations
```

I cannot understand what generates the error. It seems to me that the assignment and the way in which I import the class is correct, also because in the Evaluate class there are other functions that do not generate errors. So the problem I think is restricted to either the function or how it is invoked. Unless the Python compiler sees the method. I also tried to add the _ to the end of the function name but nothing.

I hope someone can help me or have some advice on how to better structure the files for projects. Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line that's failing:

```py
valid_locations = eval.get_valid_locations_(board)
```

It sees `eval` as the standard Python builtin function `eval`. Wherever you defined it like this:

```py
eval = evaluate.Evaluate()
```

The first line is not seeing that definition.

First of all, choose a different name that isn't a Python builtin to reduce confusion.

Then make sure that your use of the object `eval` has the correct value. If you defined it globally in a module, then `from some_module import eval`. Or you could pass it as an argument to a function where `eval.get_valid_locations_(board)` is called.

Your definition of `get_valid_locations_` has a similar problem where it calls `eval.is_valid_location(board, col)`. If `get_valid_locations_` and `is_valid_location` are both methods of the class `Evaluate`, then you should call `self.is_valid_location` instead. Not all instances of `Evaluate` should necessarily be called `eval`, nor should they have to be defined in the same file as the class.

Answer (score 0):

you created an `eval` object, and then trying to call `get_valid_locations_` function on it.

`valid_locations = eval.get_valid_locations_(board)`
this is what generates the error. eval object has no `get_valid_locations_` function.